# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

hi ihave a c# window form application that opens the edge using selenium before it is working but after months i get this error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:53335/session. The status of the exception was ReceiveFailure, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

here's the stacktrace

```
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(EdgeDriverService service, EdgeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(EdgeDriverService service, EdgeOptions options)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Edge.EdgeDriver..ctor(EdgeDriverService service)
   at XRF_Reader.DPRS_Main.XRF_Reader_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\****\Documents\projects\DPRS\DPRS\DPRS_Main.cs:line 75
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

i uses 
Selenium webdriver - v 3.141.0
selenium webdriver IE v 3.141.0

here's my code

```
   var driverService = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

                    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();                 
                    //var driver = new EdgeDriver(driverService);
                    edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(driverService);


                    edgeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Config.SpcUrl);
```

Comment: Which version of Edge browser are you using, the Legacy version Edge or Edge Chromium version? Please check the Edge browser version number and the web Driver version, make sure they are matched.

Comment: i need to try in 2 different pc and each has differenct edge browser, PC1 is MicrosoftEdge 42.17134.1.0 , MicrosoftEdge HTML 17.17134. PC2 is edgeChrominium version latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 , MicrosoftEdge HTML 17.17134.**

You could download the Release 17134 version Edge WebDriver from [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

[image]

Then use the following code to use webDriver (change the driver path to your owns):

```
 using OpenQA.Selenium;
 using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;

namespace ecwebdriver
{
    public class edgewebdriver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var driverpath = @"C:\Windows\System32"; 
            using (var driver = new EdgeDriver(driverpath))
            {
                // Navigate to Bing
                driver.Url = "https://www.bing.com/"; 
                // Find the search box and query for webdriver
                var element = driver.FindElementById("sb_form_q");

                element.SendKeys("webdriver");
                element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
                driver.Quit();
            }
       }
    }
}
```

**For the Edge Chromium version (81.0.416.72 (Official build) (64-bit))**

Download the C# binding of Selenium 4.00-alpha05 from [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) or install it [via Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/4.0.0-alpha05).

Download the matching version of Microsoft Edge Driver from [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads).

[image]

Then, using the following code (change the driver paths and website url to your owns):

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using System.Threading;

namespace ecwebdriver
{
    public class edgewebdriver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
            edgeOptions.UseChromium = true;
            edgeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"; 

            var msedgedriverDir = @"E:\webdriver";
            var driver = new EdgeDriver(msedgedriverDir, edgeOptions); 
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("<website url>");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```